# Need a reference for Welsh Powell algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, algorithms

I need a "proper and valid for undegraduate research" reference that contains the process for welsh-powell algorithm. it can be a book, published journal/article/research, or any. I'm looking for something like this:

[image]

All the researches I've found so far are either application of the algorithm in real-life, or **very difficult and rough** explanation of the process.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just use Welsh and Powell’s original paper or any research paper that cites it and gives a summary, there’s like a thousand)?

Comment: Can you give me one?

Comment: ((1)) Check out https://graphstream-project.org/doc/Algorithms/Welsh-Powell/ where you get the Exact Algorithm , with no ambiguity. ((2)) Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_coloring to get a wide perspective on the topic. ((3)) Check out https://doi.org/10.1093%2Fcomjnl%2F10.1.85 for the Original Paper. ((4)) Check out "Complexity: Knots, Colourings and Counting" Cambridge University Press ( Welsh 1993 ) with the Co-Author. ((5)) Check out "Introduction to Graph Theory" ( Douglas West 2001 ) ((6)) Check out more references given there where you will get yet more references !!!!

Comment: There's also a reference here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring.